# HttpWebRequest POST method Exception

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Currently I am using below method to post xml file content to extranet website. I am creating a new thread every 10 sec to post multiple files concurrently.

In this scenario I am getting this exception for many files : **System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out**

Though it throws this exception still content of some exception files getting posted on the website.

1) Is it correct behavior that request getting posted even though there is time out exception for some files?

2) How to handle scenario like content for some exception file getting posted and not for other? How would I make sure which content not get posted so that I can try to re-post it?

3)  Suggestions for other better implementation are welcome.

```
public void SendMessage(XmlDocument doc) {
    var httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_extranetRemitService);

    httpWReq.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
    httpWReq.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    httpWReq.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    // encode xml file contents (melFileContents is a string)
    var melMessage = doc.InnerXml;
    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(melMessage);
    //post the xml data as text/xml content type
    httpWReq.Method = "POST";
    httpWReq.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
    httpWReq.ReadWriteTimeout = -1;
    httpWReq.KeepAlive = false;
    httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
    using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try using an asynchronous call. 
      request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);

Comment: Also try increasing the 'Timeout' property (Milliseconds).
httpWReq.Timeout=10000;

Comment: This is not a complete example. You never call `httpWReq.GetResponse()`, so you can't know if the request ever made it to the server, or if the server responded. Also, it's quite possible that you don't want `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()`, but rather `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks crackhaus and Jim Mischel. Below is the working example:

```
public void SendMessage(XmlDocument doc)
    {
        var httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_extranetRemitService);
        httpWReq.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
        httpWReq.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        httpWReq.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        // encode xml file contents (melFileContents is a string)
        var melMessage = doc.InnerXml;
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(melMessage);

        //post the xml data as text/xml content type
        httpWReq.Method = "POST";
        httpWReq.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
        httpWReq.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;
        httpWReq.KeepAlive = false;
        httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
        using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
        response.Close();


    }
```